# How can I update a user's phone number in Firebase Auth with Flutter on web?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I'm using FirebaseAuth for user authentication, and I am currently trying to update a user's phone number on Flutter web.

On mobile, I have the option to use [verifyPhoneNumber](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) followed by [updatePhoneNumber](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updatePhoneNumber.html). But on web no similar methods exist.

How can I update my users' phone numbers on web?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updatephonenumber?

Answer (score 0):

On the web to change Phone Number You need to implement it from server(Admin) side.

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Do you have any resources I can look into or an example I can follow?